# error on partial view data are not pasted to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Good day. I really do not know which part will I fix. 
This is the view model

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FacultySchedViewModel> FacultyScheduleViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class FacultySchedViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Schedule { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }   
}
```

the main view- in here i will just hide or show it because it is optional.

```
@Html.Partial("_Create", new LeavesAndTrainings.ViewModels.FacultySchedViewModel())
```

and in the main view the javascript to dynamically create a textboxes in the partial view

```
<script>
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                clear_attrib();
                break;
        }
    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

this is the partial view - used BeginCollectionItem to dynamically create an index on the textboxes

```
<table class="table" id="AddSchedule">
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("FacultySchedViewModel"))
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="checkbox_style" /></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Schedule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Room, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Room, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addRow('AddSchedule')">
            <input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="btn btn-default" onclick="deleteRow('AddSchedule')">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
        ICollection<FacultySchedViewModel> schedViewModel = new List<FacultySchedViewModel>();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel, ICollection<FacultySchedViewModel> schedViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = db.Employee.Create();
            emp.ID = employeeViewModel.ID;
            emp.LastName = employeeViewModel.LastName;
            emp.FirstName = employeeViewModel.FirstName;
            db.Employee.Add(emp);

            if (schedViewModel != null)
            {
                var sched = db.FacultySchedule.Create();
                foreach (var aaa in schedViewModel)
                {
                    sched.EmployeeID = employeeViewModel.ID;
                    sched.Schedule = aaa.Schedule;
                    sched.Room = aaa.Room;
                    sched.Subject = aaa.Subject;
                } 
            }     

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

after running the create, and click the save button, `EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel` is valid and not null, but the `ICollection<FacultySchedViewModel> schedViewModel` is **null**. I tried to use only `EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel` but I do not know how to save it. I save the model in that way because there are default values and values to be extracted from other tables.

Comment: Not a lot here makes any sense. `EmployeeViewModel` contains a property for a collection of `FacultySchedViewModel` so why does you POST method have an extra parameter for `schedViewModel`. Your `Create()` method initializes some objects, but you never use them or pass them to the view. Your `BeginCollectionItem()` method prefixes all the controls with "FacultySchedViewModel" but you don't have any properties named `FacultySchedViewModel`.

Comment: My best guess is you want to create a new `Employee` and be able to dynamically add `FacultySchedule` objects?

Comment: yes, want to create a new Employee and be able to dynamically add FacultySchedule, I am really confused.. i already tried other codes for partial view..

Comment: There are 2 approaches you can take. If you use `BeginCollectionItem` in a partial, then your 'Add' button should call a method that returns the partial and adds it to the DOM (note - remove the surrounding `<table>` element - you don't want a table for each row). The other is to have a html template that you clone, update the indexers and append to the DOM. I suggest the first in your case, although it means a call to the server each time you add a row.